# Why does Maven use the wrong JDK version when running from Fish?

Tags: java, maven, fish

I run macOS Sierra, and have installed the Fish shell (https://fishshell.com/).

When I try to build a Maven project, it now gives me

```
Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 ->
```

... which means that it has picked up an older JDK which it tries to use to build my Java 8 project with.

This is made obvious by running `mvn -version`:

```
...
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
...
```

But I have `JAVA_HOME` set correctly, `echo $JAVA_HOME` in both shells give me:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and `java -version` gives me

```
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
```

and `javac -version`:

```
javac 1.8.0_112
```

`echo $PATH`gives the same result in both shells (except that in Bash, the directories are separated by `:`; in Fish, a space ):

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin
```

I have configured `maven-compiler-plugin` to for 1.8:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Why does Maven insist on using the 1.6 JDK? The same project builds fine, with the correct 1.8 JDK, when running through Bash.

Comment: Then it is not a shell problem, you should probably [configure the compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) in your maven pom.xml

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I _have_ the compiler plugin configured in my `pom.xml`. I find it hard to believe that it is not a shell problem, when the same project compiles fine with the correct JDK when running `mvn` from Bash.

Comment: Then the problem seems environmental, and it will be rather difficult that somebody here can provide an answer. You will have to check what's different in your environments and figure it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is related to an environmental condition in the OP shell configurations.

Comment: Well, it could be environment specific, or it could be to do with implementation details of Fish. Either way I hope someone could shed some light.

Comment: My environment is pretty much the same as yours (fish on macOS), but I have not set JAVA_HOME at all. I'm using maven 3.5.0 and `mvn -v` gives the following: `Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`. Setting JAVA_HOME does not make a difference in the output, so I think that's unrelated. Which maven version are you using? I have installed the latest maven (3.5.0) via homebrew (brew install maven), and recommend trying that.

Comment: @gjoranv Thanks! I was running Maven 3.0.5 - updating to 3.5.0 solved the issue. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an old version of maven, please try updating to the latest version (3.5.0), e.g. via homebrew (`brew install maven`).